# How can a huge file originate from outside of HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am a complete novice trying to learn about Hadoop and MapReduce. I understand that HDFS can store a huge file, e.g. 1 PB, by splitting it into blocks of manageable size. What I don't understand is, since such a huge file cannot be possibly stored on an HDD outside of HDFS, where could it possibly originate and be transferred from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It typically doesn't come from a single HDD, it often comes from a RAID or JBOD disk pool that is mounted on a server / cluster, more often from one or many databases.

And it doesn't need to be "one file" - it can be many files that collectively make up database tables, documents, pictures, mp3s, videos, whatever.